# Django views.py is not rendering html file?

Tags: python, django

i am sending an object to backend (django) via ajax "POST" method. in the views.py the code runs but the render statement is not executing.

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({


                url: '{% url "chout" %}',
                data: {
                   'object': object1,
                   'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrf
                  },
                  method: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                             alert("success");

                     }
                   });
```

**views.py**

```
return render(request, "mart/checkout.html", {"total": total_price, "final_bill": final_dict})
```

Everything above return statement runs smoothly but somehow the **return** line dont run. it is not showing any error or warning either and alert is not popping either.

Comment: So probably your function in views.py throws an error. Is the URL correct? Check in your terminal if the request gets a 404 or 500 etc. You could use debugging or place some print statements in your function to see where the error appears. My guess is that there is a problem with the POST method...

Comment: See my answer,  I figured out the solution

Answer (score 0):

If the alert is popping up on screen then the return line is running. Use

```
alert(data);
```

To see if the html is in there. The window is not going to apply the HTML all on its own.

Comment: Is this a class based view?

Comment: mean???  If you mean in views.Py  , it is just a normal function...  No class

Comment: Do I need to send some kind of "json" response in the render statement?

Comment: How do you know for 100% certain all other lines before return are being called?

Comment: I figured out the solution, See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For using Ajax in django,  json response must be returned not the html file